Most Ethereum Wallets are unable to properly estimate the gas for this transaction - is it a recurring bug?
These are two defi transactions that are doing a loan rollover on mainnet: borrowing money from Aave to pay off a loan and open a new loan.
When i simulate them in tenderly it looks like they run out of gas inside of nested delegatecall structures.  When I re-sim and increase the gas, they succeed.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5af9f6028290a6700dafa37d131249fb5f22f24371a8c881f6d54a97acaa2406
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe4ed4c402a66eab021bfe85ab354272ccfb299b1fb287d214ed8bb6fc64aec6c
This is a recurring problem with this particular function on this contract.  Why are web3 wallets unable to properly estimate the GasLimit for this function call?
Out frontend helps users construct these transactions and we would like to let wallets estimate the gasLimit but it seems we are forced to manually set a high gas limit here for this.   So is this a deep recurring bug with web3 libraries and wallets or something else ?
Thanks
EthereumDegen
